# Why this bash command is not working properly?

Tags: bash

I am entering this command:

```
sh -c "echo '!a'"
```

It gives an error

```
bash !a': event not found
```

This is somewhat due to the fact that ! is a special character but since I am enclosing in single quotes I should not get this.

Comment: I want the why not the how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exclamation point is used to [retrieve your bash history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3748/171560).

In your case, the error message is from your current shell, not from the shell you want to start(*). What happens is that  the single quotes don't count, since, for your current shell they are inside the double quotes, and so lose their special status and are plain characters. But inside double quotes, the history expansion with `!` still works...

If you do it the other way: `sh -c 'echo "!a"'` then it works, because the outer single quotes "hide" the `!`.

(*) You get the same error if you replace `sh` by `echo`: `echo -c "echo '!a'"`

Answer (score 0):

**`!`** is a reserved word; here a part of the sh manual:

> **Reserved Words**
>
> Reserved words are words that have special meaning to the shell and are recognized at the beginning of a
>        line and after a control operator.  The following are reserved words:
>
> ```
>        !       elif    fi      while   case
>        else    for     then    {       }
>        do      done    until   if      esac
> ```

If you want to print reserved keywords as a character:

```
sh -c "echo '"\!"a'"
```

Take a look at the sh/bash manual!

Comment: The exclamation mark `!` can be a keyword (like `if`) or a special character (like the dollar sign `$`) depending on context. In this context it's a special character. In the context of `if ! true` it's a keyword.